# Visual Studio Xamarin Android DLL

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, dll

How is it possible to create and build some activities as dynamic link library (DLL) which can be used in other apps.

Imagine I develop an android app in xamarin that has some activities. I want to import some other activities later in main app after I published it. This means that for example when a user purchases a special possibility in my app then app downloads related dll (that contain activities, resources, . . .) and placed it in proper app stored data folder which after that app can uses its contained components.

Comment: [Here is native android dynamic loading apk which you can load a activity](https://github.com/singwhatiwanna/dynamic-load-apk/blob/master/README-en.md)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot create something like "plugin-DLL". You can create a separate app that will act as a "extension" and call its services from your app. A tutorial on how to do this is available for exmple in [this blog post](http://androidsrc.net/creating-android-app-plugin-architecture-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can we use of DLL importing at runtime?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. DLLs that the app can access have to be part of the application package you deploy to store and they ale also "converted" to native libraries during the compilation.

Comment: As far as I know Xamarin has Class Library (Android) that creates DLL to use in main app.

Comment: Yes, but they cannot be imported at runtime, only during the app packaging