# Android Runtime DLL Load

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity, dll, runtime

Why it is not possible to load a DLL file at runtime and create some portion of our application dynamically?

I want to add some features (activities, resources, . . .) of my app when a user purchases of them. What is the best solution to support multi-part application that separated with something like DLLs?

Comment: Why don't you just create feature flags and unlock them with in app purchases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Xamarin Android DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218527/visual-studio-xamarin-android-dll)

Comment: Because all features size are high and for security issues. Any other alternate solutions?